# How to implement flat shading in LWJGL with index and vertex buffers?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I currently am developing a program that displays buildings and terrain in 3D in Java's LWJGL framework, which I understand is very similar to OpenGL. I am trying to differentiate between sides of buildings using flat shading. For example, a cube generated by my program should look like this:

[image]

To achieve this, I attempted to implement the method here:https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152991/how-can-i-calculate-normals-using-a-vertex-and-index-buffer.

It seems this is vertex shading, which colors every single pixel in a sort of gradient. My implementation currently looks like this:

[image]

Obviously this doesn't look like what I desired. Here are my vertex and fragment shaders:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoordinates;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoordinates;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;
out vec3 toCameraVector;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void){

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    pass_textureCoordinates = textureCoordinates;

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;
    toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

}
```

```
#version 150

in vec2 pass_textureCoordinates;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
uniform vec3 lightColour;
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;

void main(void){

    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDotl = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDotl, 0.7);
    vec3 diffuse = brightness * lightColour;

    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);

    float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
    specularFactor = max(specularFactor, 0.0);
    float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor, shineDamper);
    vec3 finalSpecular = dampedFactor * reflectivity * lightColour;


    out_Color = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * texture(modelTexture,pass_textureCoordinates) + vec4(finalSpecular, 1.0);

}
```

If a cube-shaped building I'm trying to render is indexed like so:
[image]

How can I create the array of normals programmatically for flat shading?

Answer (score 0):

The "sort of gradient" is caused by the [Specular highlights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight). If the normal vectors are normal to the faces of the cube, then a [Lambertian diffuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance) light will give you a flat look.
All you have to do is to initialize the uniform variable `reflectivity` by 0.0. (actually that's the default value).

---

It is possible to compute the face normal vectors by partial derivatives ([`dFdx`, `dFdy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml)) in the fragment shader or by the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) in the geometry shader. But this options will cause a loss of quality and speed.

<sub>See

[From within a fragment shader how do I get the surface - not vertex - normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523439/ipad-glsl-from-within-a-fragment-shader-how-do-i-get-the-surface-not-vertex/44873488#44873488)

[3D object is colored in a way that looks like a 2D object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921461/3d-object-is-colored-in-a-way-that-looks-like-a-2d-object/50931560#50931560)</sub>